# Gitlab ce in docker container issue with port

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, gitlab-omnibus

I recently installed gitlab community edition with docker-compose on my ubuntu server (16.04), which runs an nginx web server.

Sometimes the port is displayed in the url which make it load until ERR_TIMED_OUT happens.

It is always the same urls :
- new merge request
- new milestones
- link to website in email sent
(and maybe a few other that I don't have at the top of my head right now)

For example, when I try to create a merge request, I have this url :
`http://exemple.com:9090/group/project/merge_requests/new`
instead of
`http://exemple.com/group/project/merge_requests/new`

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'exemple.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://exemple.com:9090'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
      gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "account@gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "password"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
      gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
  ports:
    - '9090:9090'
    - '2224:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

The nginx server block :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]80;

    server_name exemple.com www.exemple.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```

note : nginx is not in a docker container

Comment: Maybe you should replace `external_url 'http://exemple.com:9090'` by `external_url 'http://exemple.com'`

Comment: i tried that without success

Comment: After editing you docker-compose file, did you remove/re-create your container?

Comment: Yes I did, multiple times

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the data, don't follow the below. Instead create a new container.
1- Make sure you remove the current container

```
docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm
```

2- In you docker-compose.yml file, external_url should looks like this:

```
external_url 'http://example.com'
```

3- Remove any local Gitlab configuration files previously created

```
sudo rm -rf /srv/gitlab/*
```

4- Recreate and start the container

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sadly it didn't work, I still need to bind port 9090